# node.js express server returns unexpected response to the GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get

I'm working on the weather app journal, and I am stumbling on some kind of a weird bug
I tried searching google, but I couldn't find anything helpful

so here's the problem
[image: ![image|603x386](upload://hDuEHsiCfiW3ARNhdyr5nds0yPz.png)]

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

It appears that fetch returns a response, however when I try using the .json method on fetch it gives an error, and it somehow goes to the first line of the html file.
It also appears that the response is empty, it doesn't have the data I wish to send from the server.

this is my GET route for the client side (app.js) file
[image: ![image|690x249](upload://kMhs81kWjR7cnnvEDOHo5Q7NMD.png)]

this is my code for the GET route on the server side (server.js) file
[image: ![image|518x214](upload://dYfLywO6I1ZE6gnTrMayzAltTaZ.png)]

note: the console.log("Data Sent") is never printed on the terminal
[image: ![image|393x63](upload://nmuIopdbAE1xLe3dVjde2s5nRp1.png)]

Edit: I figured out the response I'm getting from the GET request is the html file
[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please past actual code people can interact with, not images (for the code part).

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
res.send('Data sent!')
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is because of using `res.send()`, you need to use `res.json()` instead. The second will always return data as `application/json`, not as HTML which is actually causing that error. That's why it complains about the token `<`.

On more thing, try to use a single statement to return your response. So, removing `res.send('Data Sent!');`, convert to `console.log()` instead or return as part of `projectData`.

Comment: unfortunately that's not the case, I have removed it, and I'm still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

It seems that using the old path "/" resulted in a conflict, as it's the same path used to request the html.
Using a new path for the get request solved the problem.

[image]